# Perl Webservice Call SOAP Version Mismatch

Tags: perl, web-services, soap

I am calling customer's web service using Perl programming language and SOAP::Lite module.

Web service call ends with following fault string:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Header/><soap-env:Body><soap-env:Fault><faultcode>soap-env:VersionMismatch</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en">Wrong SOAP Version</faultstring><detail/></soap-env:Fault></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

As seen from message, it indicates to SOAP version. I did not understand if I am using older or higher SOAP version. When I check my SOAP::Lite version, I see "1.11"

Customer's web service includes following namespace:

```
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
```

Because it writes "2003", I wonder if I am using higher SOAP version

Comment: I would compare `soap::lite` xml envolope and request headers to these generated by https://www.soapui.org/

Comment: They are same. May it related with version of SOAP they use?

Comment: No, if headers and envelope are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I used wrong namespace value. When I opened customer's wsdl file with SOAPUI, it offers 2 versions, I used the wrong one

Comment: This answer worked for me! The version that works is the one with the "soap:" pretags, instead of "soapenv:"